# Quiero crear un programa que encripte un texto (plaintext) sumandole a cada caracter del texto un nro (arv[1]) para resultar encriptado (ciphertext)

Tags: c

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        string ciphertext = (string)malloc(strlen(plaintext) * sizeof(char));
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(plaintext); j++)
        {
            if (isalpha(plaintext[j]) == true)
            {
                if (isupper(plaintext[j]) == true)
                {
                    ciphertext[j] = plaintext[j];

                    ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] - 65 + argv[1];

                    ciphertext [j] = ciphertext[j] % 26;

                    ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] + 65;
                }
                if (islower(plaintext[j]) == true)
                {
                    ciphertext[j] = plaintext[j];

                    ciphertext[j] = (ciphertext[j] - 97 + argv[1]);

                    ciphertext [j] = ciphertext[j] % 26;

                    ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] + 97;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%c\n", ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El programa al compilar le debería dar los inputs: "./caesar" y un numero para que use este numero para encriptar el texto.

En la linea: ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] - 65 + argv[1]; me da el error: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]

De igual manera en la linea: ciphertext[j] = (ciphertext[j] - 97 + argv[1]); me da el error: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]

No entiendo que estoy haciendo incorrecto.

Comment: `argv[1]` es una cadena (char *) y no un entero. Puedes convertirlo en entero con `atoi()`

Comment: Hola abulafia. Me funcionó, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

#### Indentificación del problema

Tal y como comentaba [@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia), el problema es que el número `argv[1]` es en realidad de tipo `char *` y deberías convertirlo en `int` de la siguiente forma:

```c
ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] - 65 + atoi(argv[1]);
```

La función `atoi()` suele utilizarse para transformar los parámetros del programa en una variable de tipo entero.

#### Código final

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc == 2)
    {
      string plaintext = get_string ("plaintext: ");
      string ciphertext = (string)malloc (strlen (plaintext));
      for (int j = 0; j < strlen (plaintext); j++)
        {
          if (isalpha (plaintext[j]))
            {
              if (isupper (plaintext[j]))
                {
                  ciphertext[j] = plaintext[j];
                  ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] - 65 + atoi (argv[1]);
                  ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] % 26;
                  ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] + 65;
                }
              if (islower (plaintext[j]))
                {
                  ciphertext[j] = plaintext[j];
                  ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] - 97 + atoi (argv[1]);
                  ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] % 26;
                  ciphertext[j] = ciphertext[j] + 97;
                }
            }
          else
            ciphertext[j] = plaintext[j];
        }
      printf ("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Además de retocar las líneas donde te daba el error, he cambiado algunas cositas. Estos cambios no tienen que ver con la respuesta a tu pregunta, pero los indico por si sirven de ayuda:

- He arreglado el `printf()` del final para que escriba correctamente el mensaje cifrado por pantalla.
- Cuando llamas a `malloc()`, he omitido `* sizeof(char)`, ya que vale `1` por definición.

Espero haberte ayudado, y bienvenido a Stack Overflow :)

#### EDICIÓN

Aparentemente, en el código original se nos olvidaba escribir los caracteres no alfabéticos. De ahí el `else` que escribe el caracter tal cual, como los espacios y los signos de puntuación.

Ya he actualizado el código. Si lo compilamos y ejecutamos con una frase de ejemplo, el resultado sería el siguiente:

```sh
usuario@pc:~$:~$ gcc caesar.c -lcs50 -o caesar

usuario@pc:~$ ./caesar 11
plaintext: ¡Heyy! ¿Te apetece cifrar este texto?
ciphertext: ¡Spjj! ¿Ep lapepnp ntqclc pdep epiez?
```

Creo que ahora debería funcionar tal y como querías.

Comment: Hola javiolonchelo. Me funcionó. Me deja compliar. Pero el resultado no resulta en la encriptación del texto que ingreso en plaintext. Por alguna razón el resultado termina siendo "ciphertext: " y no me aparece el texto encriptado después. No se si sabes que es lo que estoy omitiendo para que me imprima el texto encriptado. Muchas gracias por la bienvenida a stack overflow, desde ahora es mi página favorita :)

Comment: Hola de nuevo :) Me resulta extraño que te imprima por pantalla `ciphertext:` si esa cadena no aparece en el código que he puesto como solución. ¿Es posible que hayas añadido algo para indicar por pantalla que iba a aparecer el texto encriptado y eso omita lo que queríamos mostrar? Voy a editar mi comentario porque he encontrado un fallo, échale un ojo de nuevo cuando esté por si te sirve la versión final.